# Optional generic types without having to manually specify Type

Tags: c#, generics, methods

I'm trying to create a method with an optional generic Type in order to minimize the number of queries on a SQL Database. (No need to run a query if the data is already available)

```
    // Returns proper DataTable for selected Schedule
    public static DataTable BuildReportTable<T>(Report report, List<T> InputList = null)
    {
        switch (report.ReportBase)
        {
            // Work Order Report
            case 1:
                List<ReportWorkOrder> wos = new List<ReportWorkOrder>();
                if (InputList == null)
                {
                    // Build WorkOrderReportList for report if none was passed
                    PullSQLData(() =>
                    {
                        wos = MPulseQueries.WorkOrderTableQuery();
                    }, 30, 46, "Failed to pull Work Order Data to generate table");
                }
                else
                {
                    // If WorkOrderReportList was passed, use it
                    wos = InputList as List<ReportWorkOrder>;
                }
                switch (WOFilters[report.Filter][0])
                {
                    case 0: //If all work orders report
                        return AllWOTable(report, wos);
                    case 1: //If open non PM work orders report
                        return OpenNonPMTable(report, wos);
                    case 2: //If open PM work orders report
                        return PMTable(report, wos);
                    case 3: //If open fluid change work orders report
                        return FluidChangeTable(report, wos);
                    case 4: //If custom filter work orders report
                        return CustomFilterTable(report, wos);
                    default:
                        return new DataTable();
                }
            default:
                return new DataTable();
        }
    }
```

This code compiles with no issues and performs as expected.  The only issue I'm having is that in order to call this method without the optional parameter I have to manually specify a Type.

```
DataTable DisplayedWorkOrders = BuildReportTable<ReportWorkOrder>(report);
```

So, for my question: Is there a way that I can set a default Type in the method so that I don't need to specify every time I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a non-generic overload:

```
public static DataTable BuildReportTable(Report report)
{
    return BuildReportTable<ReportWorkOrder>(report);
}
```

That's a common and perfectly respectable idiom (well, the unused type parameter chaps me just a little bit, but I'll get over it).

Otherwise, you're stuck; the parameters must flow, never mind how.

Comment: I can live with that.  This keeps it clean when calling the method, which is my goal.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a fan of the unused Type parameter either, but better hidden here as opposed to at calling time.